# Find the area of a raster created from drone data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, area, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I am trying to find the areas for a series of drone captured mosaic tiff data using ArcMap 10.8 which are irregular in shape. I have tried using Raster Calculator and multiplying by 0 to then use the Raster to Polygon tool but the Raster Calculator creates a rectangle which includes the no data values. All I want is the perimeter area of the raster, not the total extent which is what I am getting. Am I using the Raster Calculator tool incorrectly? I have the Spatial Analyst extension only with the Basic licence. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Con(~IsNull(Raster),1) and convert to polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Reclassifying](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) your raster, with all data values set to 1, no data set to 0. Then use Raster to Polygon as you already attempted. You've got the right idea, but multiplying by zero will turn any value (data or no data) to 0, which is why right now you've only gotten the total extent in your polygon.

Comment: So I tried reclassifying all values 1-255 as 1 and 0/No data as 0 and it has still produced the entire extent in value 1. The attribute data shows two values with counts that make sense, however it's still just one rectangle. Classifying from 0-255 as 1 and no data as 0 gives me one value in the reclassified raster. So I feel like I'm on the right path with the latter, but its still only producing the extent.

Comment: Odd. Going off of past experienced and double checked by documentation (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polygon.htm) that doesn't seem quite like expected behavior. Editing your question to add some screenshots of your exact parameters and settings might be helpful in troubleshooting.

Comment: Just going to hand digitize them as the cell size is super small and takes forever to calculate but I will try to troubleshoot more and see if I can find an answer.